# What takes precedence? My Gmail filter or Gmail's spam detection?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention

I create a Gmail filter that makes emails coming from certain email ID (say `abc@gmail.com`) skip my inbox and go to "trash". Now suppose Gmail's spam detector finds that a message from this address looks like spam. Then where shall such a mail be sent - "trash" or "spam" folder?

Answer (score 5):

If a message matches your filters, those will always take precedence, I believe.

That's why you can also opt to "mark it as Non-spam".